# How would I stop audio that is playing from pydub when using a voice command?

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pydub, assistant

I am trying to stop audio from playing when I say stop, but it does not seem to work. The code I currently have is very rudimentary, and is as follows:

```py
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pydub
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts
import time
import os

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


def __innit__(self):
...

        self.current_audio = None
        self.stop_audio = False
...

if text == "stop":
            self.speaker.say("Stopping current command. Returning to listening mode.")
            self.speaker.runAndWait()
            self.command_event.clear()
            self.current_audio.close()
elif "play" in text:
            audio_folder = "music"
            audio_files = [f for f in os.listdir(audio_folder) if f.endswith(".mp3")]
            if audio_files:
                if "loop" in text:
                    while self.command_event.is_set():
                        for audio_file in audio_files:
                            audio_file_path = os.path.join(audio_folder, audio_file)
                            audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file_path)
                            self.current_audio = audio
                            play(self.current_audio)
                else:
                    audio_file = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(audio_folder, audio_files[0]))
                    self.current_audio = audio_file
                    play(self.current_audio)
            else:
                self.speaker.say("Sorry, I couldn't find any audio files in the music folder.")
                self.speaker.runAndWait()
        else:
            if text is not None:
                response = self.assistant.request(text)
                if response is not None:
                    self.speaker.say(response)
                    self.speaker.runAndWait()
```

How would I go about stopping the audio? Should I define `.close()`? Pyaudio has a `.stop()` in `pydub.playback`, but when I try to use that in this program, it doesn't work. Pyaudio had not been working on my computer and I have tried everything to get it to work, but I just cant seem to. `Playback.stop()` does not work.